# Session cookie javaScript

Tags: javascript

In Europe we should warn users that if used coockie.Pour that I would like to open a popup that opens once a sesssion but check any button by which it accepts coockie. Do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to reword your question a little bit better? You want a button confirm to if the user wants to accept a cookie?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. yes it is exactly that

Comment: as here http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/902044Capturede769cran20140712a768120157.png

Comment: It should be quite simple, using the button to set a simple "cookiesAllowed" value and an if statement to check that value. If you want more specific help, maybe try posting some code?